# Debugging Inheritance Class

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, inheritance

I am receiving the following errors when running my code and it seems as if I had tried everything to eliminate them but nothing is appearing to work.  **Any suggestions or explanation of what I be may doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.**  Here are the errors:
In my code at "class Integer : public Number" it says "! Expected class name"
and at "Integer(const Double &d);" it says "! Unknown type name 'Double'; did you mean 'double'?"

Here is may actual code in **Integer.h** which contains the errors:

```
#ifndef INTEGER
#define INTEGER

#include "Number.h"
#include "Double.h"

namespace MyNamespace {

using std::string;

class Double;

class Integer : public Number

{

private:

    void create(int i);

    bool NaN(string s, int iCount);

    bool nan;

public:

    //Constructors

    Integer();

    Integer(int i);

    Integer(const Integer &i);

    Integer(const Double &d);  //ERROR HERE = "Unknown type 'Double'"

    Integer(string s);


    void equals(int i);

    void equals(string s);

    Integer add(const Integer &i);

    Integer sub(const Integer &i);

    Integer mul(const Integer &i);

    Integer div(const Integer &i);

    Integer add(int i);

    Integer sub(int i);

    Integer mul(int i);

    Integer div(int i);

    int toInt() const;


    //Print
    void printInteger();


    // operator overloads

    Integer operator + (const Integer &i);

    Integer operator - (const Integer &i);

    Integer operator * (const Integer &i);

    Integer operator / (const Integer &i);

    Integer operator = (const Integer &i);

    Integer operator = (int i);

    Integer operator = (string s);

    string toString() const;

    bool operator == (const Integer &i);

    bool operator == (int i);

    bool operator != (const Integer &i);

    bool operator != (int i);


    bool isNan();

};
}

#endif
```

**Number.h**

```
#ifndef NUMBER
#define NUMBER

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace MyNamespace {

using std::string;

class Number : public string
{

public:

    Number();

    Number(string s);


};

}

#endif
```

**Double.h**

```
#ifndef DOUBLE
#define DOUBLE

#include "Number.h"
#include "Integer.h"

namespace MyNamespace
{

class Integer;    

class Double : public Number

{

private:

    void create(double d);

    bool NaN(string s, int dCount);

    bool nan;

public:

    // Constructors

    Double();

    Double(double d);

    Double(const Double &d);

    Double(const Integer &i);  //ERROR HERE = "Unknown type 'Integer'"

    Double(string s);


    void equals(double d);

    void equals(string s);

    Double add(const Double &d);

    Double sub(const Double &d);

    Double mul(const Double &d);

    Double div(const Double &d);

    Double add(double d);

    Double sub(double d);

    Double mul(double d);

    Double div(double d);

    double toDouble() const;

    //Print
    void printDouble();

    // operator overloads

    Double operator + (const Double &d);

    Double operator - (const Double &d);

    Double operator * (const Double &d);

    Double operator / (const Double &d);

    Double operator = (const Double &d);

    Double operator = (double d);

    Double operator = (string s);

    string toString() const;

    bool operator == (const Double &d);

    bool operator == (double d);

    bool operator != (const Double &d);

    bool operator != (double d);


    bool isNan();

};
}

#endif
```

Comment: What's in Number.h and Double.h?

Comment: It's really important to learn how to interpret error messages. The compiler is telling you that it doesn't know what Number and Double mean. In particular, it's telling you that Double is an unknown type. Now, why might that be the case? Figure out why and where your understanding diverges from the compilers. So, why do you think it should know Double? Did you define/declare it? Where? Is it definition/declaration correct? Any typos? Correct namespace?

Comment: I suspect you are using `#include "Integer.h"` in Double.h. If that's the case, you need to remove that line from Double.h and remove `#include "Double.h"` from Integer.h. Just use forward declarations in each file.

Comment: You are using two name spaces -- `Roman` and `MyNamespace` -- you must make the classes fully qualified including the namespace to use them across namespaces.

Comment: You also have the cyclic include problem mentioned by R Sahu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify Number.h. Don't include "Integer.h" and "Double.h" in it. You are not even referencing anything from those files in this file.

```
#ifndef NUMBER  // I'd recommend using NUMBER_H instead of just NUMBER
#define NUMBER

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

namespace MyNamespace {

class Number : public string
{
public:

    Number();

    Number(string s);

};

}

#endif
```

Remove `#include "Integer.h"` from Double.h. Similarly, remove `#include "Double.h"` from Integer.h. Add a forward declaration of `Integer` in Double.h and a forward declaration of `Double` in Integer.h.

```
#ifndef DOUBLE
#define DOUBLE

#include "Number.h"

namespace MyNamespace
{
   class Integer;
```

Comment: Everything is now working accept the "Double(const Integer &i);" which now says "Unknown type name 'Integer'"

Comment: @user1 did you mean "except the"? If you did, except what?

Comment: You have to provide a forward declaration of `Integer` in Double.h.

Comment: I made my corrections to what I have now, the one error still persists

Comment: If you can post the minimal code that produces the error, it will be helpful to identify the problem.

Comment: Each time i run it the error switches between the Double.h file in "Double(const Integer &i);" which says "Unknown type name 'Integer'" and the Integer.h file in "Integer(const Double &d);" which says "Unknown type name 'Double'"

Answer (score 2):

You have a circular dependency between Integer and Double. If you do not utilize these inline you might just have a forward declarations and remove the #include "Integer.h" and #include "Double.h".

If you want to use these inline you might include additional files for the inline implementations:

```
#ifndef NUMBER_H
#define NUMBER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


namespace MyNamespace {

// Please do not put the using into the global namespace
using std::string;

class Number : public string {};

}
#endif

// =============================================================================

#ifndef INTEGER_H
#define INTEGER_H

#include "Number.h"

namespace MyNamespace {

class Double;
class Integer : public Number
{
public:
    Integer(const Double &d);
};
}

#endif

#include "Integer.tcc"

// =============================================================================

// Integer.tcc
#ifndef INTEGER_H
#error Please include Integer.h instead
#endif

#include "Double.h"

namespace MyNamespace {
    inline Integer::Integer(const Double &d) {}
}

// =============================================================================

#ifndef DOUBLE_H
#define DOUBLE_H

#include "Number.h"

namespace MyNamespace
{

class Integer;
class Double : public Number
{
public:
    Double(const Integer &i);
};
}

#endif

#include "Double.tcc"

// =============================================================================

// Double.tcc
#ifndef DOUBLE_H
#error Please include Double.h instead
#endif

#include "Integer.h"

namespace MyNamespace {
    inline Double::Double(const Integer &d) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wager that Number and Double, if defined at all, are defined in a namespace and need to be qualified.