# Mutual inclusion with inline function in C++

Tags: c++

I want to write some code like this: an `A` object calls its class `B` type member `b`'s member function `DoSomething`, and in class `B`'s `DoSomeOtherThing` member function, it calls `A`'s `Notify` member function. See the code below:

Class A:

```
class A
{
    B b;

public:
    A() : b(*this)
    {
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        b.DoSomething();
    }

    void Notify()
    {
    }
};
```

Class B:

```
class B
{
    A &a;

public:
    B(A &a) : a(a)
    {
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
    }

    void DoSomeOtherThing()
    {
        a.Notify();
    }
};
```

The problem is I want to keep the functions inline, so the code should be in header files. I can't simply include each other because they may cause mutual inclusion, and I don't know if a forward declaration can be use in this situation. I can write the implementation in source file but they will not be inline functions. So, how can I make the code work?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440230/debugging-inheritance-class/23440630#23440630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the definitions of the member functions out of the class definition and still keep them inline (and thus in the header) by explicitly prefixing their out-of-class definition with `inline`. After you've done that, you'll notice that

- the class definition of `B` can easily be moved before the member function definitions of `A`, solving the issue of accessing `B` from those members, and
- the class definition of `A` only needs a forward declaration of `B`, so adding `class B;` before the definition of `A` fixes that issue.

Doing those two changes is sufficient to solve your problem.